# How to define a function using its declaration?

Tags: typescript

Having a declaration like

```
 type MyFunction = (s: string, a: number) => string;
```

I'd like to define an function like

```
class SomeClass {
    myFunction(s: string, a: number) : string {
    }
}
```

but using the `MyFunction` type. I could use `ReturnType` and maybe the arguments, but I wonder, whether there's something more straightforward. Letting `SomeClass` implement an interface probably does the job, but then I have one more thing to declare (which is pain as it's hard to find good names for it all).

Comment: You can write `class SomeClass implements Record<"myFunction", MyFunction> {...}` but that doesn't save you from writing the signature inside the class definition (see [microsoft/TypeScript#32082](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/32082) and many others); I'm not sure what specific issue you're trying to solve so I'm not sure if this is sufficient or if you need something else.

Comment: @jcalz There's no real problem, just something I'm missing: I actually wanted to declare a function so that's it's type is obvious; ideally collocated like in `myFunction: MyFunction`. Given that there are multiple ways of how to declare or define function, I thought it could be possible.

Comment: @jcalz Yes, please do.

Answer (score 0):

Like this?

```
type MyFunction = (s: string, a: number) => string;

class SomeClass {
    myFunction: MyFunction = (s, a) => {
        return '';
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to define it as normal function

```
class SomeClass {
  public myFunction: MyFunction = function(s, a) {
    // you can still access this. if you need.
    return `${s}${a}`;
  }
}
```

Or you can use an arrow function, but then you lose access to `this`.

Answer (score 0):

it depends how you wish to use function, in example you can make it optional

```
    type MyFunction = (s: string, a: number) => string;

    type MyFunctionMaybe = ((s: string, a: number) => string) | undefined;

    function factory(place: any):  MyFunction{
      throw Error();
    }

    class SomeClass {
      myFunction: MyFunction = factory(SomeClass);

      myFunctionOptional?: MyFunction;

      myFunctionMaybe: MyFunctionMaybe;
    }
```

[typescript playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAsiBiBXAdgY2ASwPbKgXigAoBnALimOACcNkBzAGigENzlEBbAIwioEp8APgrVadANwAoSaEiwEKdNmQxmIHviIlylGvSaso7brwF5husQIA+UFABMIAM1oR7UyU8WYcUJ83QsKhBCMAAbAIhyZmQQPnJ5JDQfZABvSSgoYAALKiwAdygAUSo8qkI+KQBfaVQI4mIoAGUsDggAYXrG9MyOBWTlcjgkpV8Cf0Dgwha2zuYGyozMpb6RlIB5MBTmMIB+If7R5A9ew5TVdSjE72ULnmqgA)

Comment: You're defining fields on the instance (just like arrow functions do), while I'd prefer to define functions on the prototype. Use `console.log('myFunction' in Object.getPrototypeOf(new SomeClass()));` to see it.